# Switch 100V with MOSFET Highside

Tags: mosfet

I have 100V from Buck Converter and wish to switch this wit PIC. PIC Vcc = 3V. I need High side switch, eg. my load should be GND connected. I find some solutions, but no one work for me.

Comment: How much current, and how often will it be switched on and off? What exactly is the load? Does your convertor have isolated output? What does 'Bust' mean?

Comment: @laptop2d It's not clear that your edit is correct.

Comment: We shall see, I'm willing to take bets since there is no such thing as a bust conbverter

Comment: @DusanPetek Please provide a better problem statement of what you intend to do and then ask a question. Also include a schematic and use the schematic editor tool.

Comment: @laptop2d, why would you say so about bust converters? At 100V one can easily make a busted one :-)

Comment: What kind of solutions have you found and why they don't work for you?

Comment: No schematic, not clear what you're trying to achieve. No idea what a "100 V Buck converter" is. Probably you think it is but it is likely something different. You show none of the solutions you found, how do you expect us to come up with a solution if you don't show us these ? If you want proper help, as the question properly and not in this "lazy" way.

Comment: Without know how much current the load will require its impossible to put anything but a generalised circuit up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out some handy devices I've used in the past called Photovoltaic Isolators. They provide isolation between input and output much like a transistor or diode based opto-isolator, but they generate current/voltage so you can use them to directly drive a MOSFET gate.

They find application is Mosfet based SSR circuits.

They are not particularly fast as there is limited current to drive the gate, so they may not be suitable for PWM type applications, but if you want something simple to drive a switch, take a look.

Vishay's VOM1271 is a good place to start.

http://www.vishay.com/optocouplers/list/product-83469/